# How to get all sites from a given domain?

Tags: web-scraping

If this is not the right place to ask this kind of question please tell me where I can ask this.

Basically I want to scrape news from a site. It has the following format:

The link to a specific news:
https://www.presseportal.de/blaulicht/pm/4970/1345341

Where https://www.presseportal.de/blaulicht/pm/4970/ is the root and 1345341 is a random number.Only the random number changes.

So how can I find all the news that belong to this specific root?
(There is no link to them on the website, because they only show 300 pages)

Comment: This specific site have API, try to get the data by API - it is more polite and less painfull process.  https://api.presseportal.de/

Comment: I already wrote them, they told me it is not possible with an API

Comment: How do you even know those articles are there beyond the 300 they are displaying? They could be, don't get me wrong but it seems crazy to assume. Do you have any way of verifying that? Why can't you just scrape the 300 that you can actually see?

Comment: you can google older news for example.
Here is a news from 2009, you can't find the link on the normal site anywhere:
https://www.presseportal.de/blaulicht/pm/4970/1345341

 --- I scraped the aprox. 8000 news from the 300 sites but I want more data, since breaking them down by region or crime gives very low numbers

Answer (score 0):

Use paginated url like [www.presseportal.de/blaulicht/**nr**/4970/{number}](http://www.presseportal.de/blaulicht/**nr**/4970/%7Bnumber%7D) it will give you page of 27 titles. Then **scrape** links from titles.
Than just increment the {number} and get next page until you get to the end.

- [www.presseportal.de/blaulicht/**nr**/4970/27](http://www.presseportal.de/blaulicht/**nr**/4970/27)
- [www.presseportal.de/blaulicht/**nr**/4970/54](http://www.presseportal.de/blaulicht/**nr**/4970/54)
- ...

Comment: this only gets me to page 300 or https://www.presseportal.de/blaulicht/nr/4970/8073
if you try to increment after that it fails